# Bootstrap elements among themselves

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have two divs. In the normal browser the two divs are side by side.
But if i draw less the browser the first div lost his height an the second div slips into the first element.
I have tried to set the body to min height 100% but no change.

```html
<div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8">
<h1>Inventar</h1>
<div class="inventar">
 <div class="img_div" id="822273846">
  <img src="IMG URL" alt="" class="img-responsive">
 </div>
</div>
  
<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2">
<div class="item-overview" id="detail_822273846">
  <!-- IMAGE -->
  <img src="IMG URL" alt="" class="img-responsive">
  <!-- HR -->
  <hr>
  <!-- NAME -->
  <h3>P90 | Sand Spray</h3>
  <!-- DESCRIPTION -->
  <p>Easily recognizable for its unique bullpup design, the P90 a great weapon to shoot on the move due to its high-capacity magazine and low recoil. It has been spray-painted freehand with short, thick lines in contrasting colors.

<i>Perfect for the insurgent on the go</i></p>
  <p>Type: Consumer Grade SMG</p>
  <!-- HR -->
  <hr>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" value="Sell"></button> 
  <br/>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: 1) It is not clear what you are trying to achieve. 2) You are missing one closing `</div>` tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For everything under 768px, the `xs` attribute is used for column size.

Therefore, you need to add 'col-xs-[size]' to your divs. 
Example:

```
  <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2  col-xs-2">
```

Additionally, it's always a good practice to wrap your columns in a `row` if you want them inline.

**Snippet:**

```html
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />


 <div class="row">
<div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8">
<h1>Inventar</h1>
<div class="inventar">
 <div class="img_div" id="822273846">
  <img src="IMG URL" alt="" class="img-responsive">
 </div>
</div>
   </div>
  
<div class="col-lg- col-md-2 col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
<div class="item-overview" id="detail_822273846">
  <!-- IMAGE -->
  <img src="IMG URL" alt="" class="img-responsive">
  <!-- HR -->
  <hr>
  <!-- NAME -->
  <h3>P90 | Sand Spray</h3>
  <!-- DESCRIPTION -->
  <p>Easily recognizable for its unique bullpup design, the P90 a great weapon to shoot on the move due to its high-capacity magazine and low recoil. It has been spray-painted freehand with short, thick lines in contrasting colors.

<i>Perfect for the insurgent on the go</i></p>
  <p>Type: Consumer Grade SMG</p>
  <!-- HR -->
  <hr>
  <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" value="Sell"></button> 
  <br/>
</div>
</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean on smaller screen sizes. If so, you'll need to add xs column classes to make the divs appear side by side (otherwise they'll stack up)

```
<div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8">
```

and

```
<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-2  col-xs-2">
```

This is assuming you are missing a closing  tag before the 2nd div.